# Run as different user in IE

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-9

I would like to know the mechanism of running as different user.
As I heard that by doing this it syncs the user's password on machine.

I work for IT Service Desk in a organisation and wanted to understand the mechanism.

Could some one help me in understanding.

Regards,
Preethi

Comment: You do realize running as different user actually means you need to run it using their username and password? So you actually need to have the username and password of the other user. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding

> I would like to know the mechanism of running as different user.

Answer is you can just right click on the icon and something as below should show:

[image]

If it doesn't appear check [Windows: Enable “Run as different user](https://www.technipages.com/enable-right-click-run-as)

For  this:

> As I heard that by doing this it syncs the user's password on machine.

I do not have an answer for that as it is really vague statement.

Comment: Sometimes you may need to hold down on the **Shift** button on the keyboard and then right click on the icon to get the **Run as different user** option as well.